# Adding a toolbar to a navigation controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, ios5, toolbar

[image]I am completely new to ios development and I am only interested in developing for ios5.

I have an app with some scenes, they are mostly tableviews. I also use a navigation controller

I however need to add some status text and buttons that are always visible in all scenes and thought that a toolbar added to the navigation controller should do the trick.

so i thought that i should only have to drag out a toolbar in storyboard to the navigation controller, but it does not stick there. I can add it to the bar underneath with first responder and navigation controller but that does not help me (small icons).
I can also not add it to my table view (but if i drag out a plain view I can add it there)

do I have to make my own custom navigation class that the navigate view uses and then programatically add my toolbar?

Comment: Yes nikans, I was new to stackoverflow before and did not quite get it, but now i am a changed man :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Had the same question recently. Check Attributes Inspector in your ViewController's properties  in storyboard. There you can define a Bottom Bar.

[image: Attributes Inspector]

Comment: You're right, now you should bind it to a property in your view controller and it'll work flawlessly.

Comment: Excellent, thank you I will try that and hopefully get it all to work

Comment: I dont fully understand why I need to wire anything up (nor who) because I added a button and linked it to another view/scene and it worked great, so I don't really see why i need code. What am I missing?

Comment: No, it's all right, but if you want to reference this toolbar in your code (I usually do), you have to bind it to your view controller. Otherwise it's ok just to leave it to storyboards.

Answer (score 2):

Well, inside the `UINavigationController`, you should have something... A `UIViewController` for instance. You can easily add a `UIToolBar` by dragging the object inside the `UIView` of the `UIViewController`. What might being happening is that as the root view you have the `UITableView`, in that case I think you can't do that. But to better understand, just take a small print screen of your StoryBoard.

Comment: I added a picture, I don't have a view in my navigation controller, am I doing something wrong? Also excuse the big gaps but I am using vnc to a mac mini and for some weird reason I cant move scenes once I have placed them :-(

Comment: That's the behavior of TableViews in storyboards, you can't add subviews except for TableViewCells. It's quite logically if you think about that.

Comment: THe problem here Rickard, is that you need to put an UIView, and inside it you put your UITableView. That's why you can't add your UIToolBar...

Comment: That's right. But how to get UITableViewController working that way?

Comment: Humm, I rarely use UITableViewController. But still, on viewDidLoad put the following: self.tableView=myTableIBOutlet. (Create an IBOutelet for your table)

Comment: I hade it that way before Jacky Boy but then i removed my normal view and replace it with a UITableViewController and got a lot of stuff for free. But nikans solution seems to work wonders.

Comment: Lol, sometimes is better to understand concepts like UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource in a more detailed way, than getting stuff for free. :P Besides, you get more flexibility while adopting those protocols. But if you are happy with nikans answer, its ok. :D

Answer (score 2):

If you zoom up to 100% on the storyboard it should drag.